# Riemann-Stieltjes sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1)}n \right) +\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right) \right) \left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1)}n \right) -\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right) \right) \right]$$

Comment: It is just the Riemann-Stiltjes sum for $2\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\, d\sin x=2\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 x\,dx=2\pi.$

Comment: Are you referring to the approximating sum $S(P,f,g)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(c_k)(g(x_{k+1})-g(x_i))$, where $P=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n \mid a=x_0< \cdots < x_n=b\}$?

Comment: Pretty much except what you have is more like a trapezoid rule sum (which makes no real difference in the end, of course).

Answer (score 1):

First, by trigonometric identities involving sums and products, we have
$$\begin{align}
 &\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1)}n \right) +\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right) \right) \left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1)}n \right) -\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right) \right)  \\ &=4\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1/2)}n \right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1/2)}n\right)\cos\frac{\pi}n\sin\frac{\pi}n \\
&=2\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1/2)}n\right)\sin\frac{2\pi}n.\\
&=\left( 2\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi(k+1/2)}n\right)-1+1\right)\sin\frac{2\pi}n \\
&=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi(k+1/2)}n\right)\sin\frac{2\pi}n+\sin\frac{2\pi}n.\end{align}
$$

By Euler's theorem, the sum over $k=1$ through $k=n$ becomes
$$
\Re \left(  \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ 4\pi i\frac{k+1/2}n } \right) \sin\frac{2\pi}n + n\sin\frac{2\pi }n.
$$

By geometric sum formula, we have
$$
\Re \left( e^{2\pi i /n}  e^{4\pi i/n} \frac{ e^{4\pi i }-1}{ e^{4\pi i/n} -1} \right)\sin\frac{2\pi}n + n\sin\frac{2\pi}n.
$$
We see that the quantity inside paranthesis is zero because $e^{4\pi i}=1$. Then as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we are left with 
$$
n\sin \frac{2\pi}n = \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}n}{\frac1n}\rightarrow 2\pi.
$$

Therefore, the limit is $2\pi$.

Comment: I am so sorry, but between the sine functions the sign is negative, not positive. The sign between cosine functions is still positive, at least. If possible, can you modify your answer accordingly? Thanks, and again sorry.